# fiddler и запросы (HttpURLConnection)

Tags: java, консоль

Не получается отследить запрос при помощи Fiddler'a (обычное консольное приложение), подскажите в чем проблема, спасибо.

```
    URL myUrl = new URL("http://pro-java.ru");
    HttpURLConnection myUrlCon =
            (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
    // Вывести метод запроса
    System.out.println("Метод запроса: " +
            myUrlCon.getRequestMethod());
    // Вывести код ответа
    System.out.println("Ответное сообщение: " +
            myUrlCon.getResponseMessage());
    // Получить список полей и множество ключей из заголовка
    Map<String, List<String>> myMap = myUrlCon.getHeaderFields();
    Set<String> myField = myMap.keySet();
    System.out.println("\nДалее следует заголовок:");
    // Вывести все ключи и значения из заголовка
    for(String k : myField) {
        System.out.println("Ключ: " + k + " Значение: "
                + myMap.get(k));
    }
```

Comment: Прокси пропиши явно. Вероятно, java не использует системные настройки по умолчанию.

Comment: 'System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
 System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
 System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8888");
 System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8888");' так? нашел в одном топике, но эффекта не дало это

Comment: в общем если стоит http в адресе, то вроде работает, правда на любую страницу выдает ошибку 400 или 404, если https стоит, то вообще не отслеживает, неправильно значит прокси прописал, в чем проблема?

Comment: Для https надо разрешить расшифровку https в настройках фиддлера и подтвердить установку его сертификата в систему.